# Jasper Reports: Exporting report to multiple files

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm developing a jrxml template for generate job candidate's resume. The candidates are in my database.

I need to generate a Word file (.docx) for 1 record (by job candidate), as the image below:

[image: Word file with individual candidate resume]

How can I make Jasper generate one file for each record of my SQL query? And export these files to Word?

I saw there is a parameter called *PAGE_INDEX* exporter. But I did not find how to use it ...

Can someone help me please?

**Note 1:** My reports are not generated by JasperServer. I developed a Java program to generate them and send reports by email.

**Note 2:** The number of pages for each candidate may be different.

**Updating status**

I managed to generate one record per file. But I could only generate the file to the first record.
I need to generate other files for the remaining records.
I'm still with the another problem too: how to separate into separate files when the number of pages for each record (candidate entity) can change?

```
final JRDocxExporter exporter = new JRDocxExporter();
        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(new java.io.File("/home/admin/resume candidate.docx")));
        SimpleDocxReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleDocxReportConfiguration();
        configuration.setPageIndex(0);
        exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
        exporter.exportReport();
```

Comment: You should consider to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) some answers on all your old question, for how to accept see the [tour], without accept the question is still open (no useful solution) and future users have no reference

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLUTION**

I solved the problem by inserting a variable in the footer of each page with the expression: $V{REPORT_COUNT}, which have record count that is in the Detail Band:
[image]

After that, the Java program do loop between the pages of JasperPrint object.
So, i locate that element that tells me what page belongs to candidate.
Based on this information and storing candidate index data and its pages (in a *HashMap > mapCandPage*), I can determine the page that starts and the page ends for each candidate. And that way I can export one document for each candidate record.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        File relJasperArqFile = new File("Candidate Resume Template.jasper");
        Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.getNewConnectionSQLDRIVER();

        JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(relJasperArqFile);

        JasperPrint jasperPrint
                = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
                        null,
                        conn);

        final JRDocxExporter exporter = new JRDocxExporter();
        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));

        List<JRPrintPage> listPrintPage = jasperPrint.getPages();

        int candIdx = 0;
        int fileIdx = 0;
        int lastCandIdx = 0;
        HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> mapCandPage = new HashMap<>();
        for (int pageIdx = 0; pageIdx < listPrintPage.size(); pageIdx++) {
            JRPrintPage page = listPrintPage.get(pageIdx);
            candIdx = getCandIdx(page);

            if (!mapCandPage.containsKey(candIdx)) {
                mapCandPage.put(candIdx, (new ArrayList<>()));
            }
            mapCandPage.get(candIdx).add(pageIdx);

            if (pageIdx > 0 && candIdx != lastCandIdx) {
                fileIdx++;
                exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(new File(String.format("Candidate Resume %d.docx", fileIdx))));
                SimpleDocxReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleDocxReportConfiguration();
                configuration.setStartPageIndex(mapCandPage.get(lastCandIdx).get(0));
                configuration.setEndPageIndex(mapCandPage.get(lastCandIdx).get(mapCandPage.get(lastCandIdx).size() - 1));
                exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
                exporter.exportReport();

            }

            lastCandIdx = candIdx;

        }
        fileIdx++;
        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(new File(String.format("Candidate Resume %d.docx", fileIdx))));
        SimpleDocxReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleDocxReportConfiguration();
        configuration.setStartPageIndex(mapCandPage.get(lastCandIdx).get(0));
        configuration.setEndPageIndex(mapCandPage.get(lastCandIdx).get(mapCandPage.get(lastCandIdx).size() - 1));
        exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
        exporter.exportReport();

    }

    public static Integer getCandIdx(JRPrintPage page) {
        JRPrintElement lastRowNumber = page.getElements().get(page.getElements().size() - 1);
        return Integer.parseInt(((JRTemplatePrintText) lastRowNumber).getFullText());
    }
```

This is a test and my code is not optimized. If anyone has suggestions or a better idea, please post here. Thank you.